# Wrapping jQuery Autocomplete in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, jquery-autocomplete

I've found nice working implementation of wrapping jQuery datepicker in AngularJS [here on GitHub](https://github.com/shyamseshadri/angularjs-book/tree/master/chapter8/datepicker) and then tried to do the same with jQuery Autocomplete.

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testCntrl">
    <input type='text' autocomplete ng-model='$parent.currentSuggestion' static-data='staticData' select=inform(suggestion) /><br />
    Current Suggestion - {{currentSuggestion}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.directives']).controller('testCntrl', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.currentSuggestion = '';    
    $scope.staticData = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];    
    $scope.inform = function (suggestion) {
        console.log(suggestion);
    };
});
```

and autocomplete.js

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('autocomplete', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
            select: '&',
            data: '=staticData'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) {
                return;
            }
            var updateModel = function (suggestion) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(suggestion);
                });
            };
            var options = {};
            options.minLength = 1;
            options.source = scope.data;
            options.select = function (event, ui) {
                updateModel(ui.item.value);
                if (scope.select) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.select({ suggestion: ui.item.value });
                    });
                }
            };
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
            element.autocomplete(options);
        }
    };
});
```

And it happens that in my case this line `ngModel.$setViewValue(suggestion);` doesn't update the `currentSuggestion`field at all!

What is more interesting that initializing controller with some predefined `currentSuggestion` like  `$scope.currentSuggestion = 'Java';` results in `ngModel.$viewValue` being `undefined` in a $render method!

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3y0eVfhyte06KZTdiUd?p=preview)

Could someone explain me why it behave like this and correct my mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

I think because $parent.scope doesn't have 'currentSuggestion' implemented so it becomes undefined, while this should work because it gets value from current controller scope:

`<input type='text' autocomplete ng-model='currentSuggestion'`